# which is correct? "traffic congestion" or "traffic congestions"

Tags: word-usage

i know the word "congestion" is uncountable itself. However, in some articles, I saw "traffic congestions." I am wondering if the usage below is correct or not.

1. Traffic congestion happens a lot during holidays.
2. If there are serious congestions on roads, we may be late for the party.
3. A severe congestion was seen on roads yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

"congestion" usually refers to the general concept of congested rows, so it's uncountable.

But it can also be used to refer to a specific instance of congestion. In this sense, it's countable, and this is how it's being used in examples 2 and 3.

I don't think the second sense is very common, we usually refer to these as "traffic jams".

Comment: It's so unusual that I think we need some endorsement that it's allowable.